# C++ - cin spams terminal

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get input for an integer in C++ through `cin` and when I try this:

```
int port = 0;

do
{
  std::cout << "Enter port for server: ";
  std::cin >> port;
} while (port <= 0);
```

It spams my terminal with "Enter port for server: " if I don't enter a valid integer. How do I handle this situation and why does this spam my terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not validating input. Ideally what you should do is take input as strings then perform the conversion to the type you want after. If you do want to take them as integers, You can check the value of cin after the user enters input. If input is invalid, the failbit in cin is set.

```
int main(){
    int port = 0;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter port for server: ";
        if(!(cin >> port)){//error occurred
            std::cout << "invalid input" << std::endl;
            cin.clear();//Clear the error
            break;
        }
    } while (port <= 0);

}
```

Comment: How about `if(!(cin >> port))`? Check if the input succeeded, not for a bad stream after.

Comment: Yes @RetiredNinja that works just fine. Just caution with where the parenthesis are for the OP. I made the adjustments to your recommendation.

Comment: I have the following code:

```do
  {
    std::cout << "Enter port for server: ";

    if ((std::cin >> port))
    {
      std::cin.clear();
    }
  } while (port <= 0);```

And my terminal still gets spammed. I want it to do the do-while until it gets valid input.

Comment: Oh. You don't want it to break out of the loop? Then follow what the user below me @Benjamin Kljuno recommended. call `std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` To clear the input stream and take input again and remove the break. Also my answer should not be marked as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cout << "Enter valid port, please. " << std::endl;
}

while (std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin >> port;
}
```

After std::cin fails, you need to clear error flag. You don't even have to use fail function:

`while (!(std::cin >> port)) { std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(); }`